# Configuring Varnish 6 with grace mode, vcl_hit is never executed

Tags: varnish

I'm trying to configure varnish 6.0.0 as a cache server when the webserver is going down for maintanance but I can't get the expected behavior.

I have the next configuration (using grace mode):

```
vcl 4.0;

import directors;
import std;

backend default {
    .host = "some.server.com";
    .port = "80";
    .probe = {
        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .interval = 5s;
        .timeout = 1s;
        .window = 5;
        .threshold = 3;
    }
}

sub vcl_recv {
    std.syslog(180, "RECV: recv");

    #Cache - grace mode
    set req.http.grace = "none";
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    std.syslog(180, "RECV: backend");

    #Cache - grace mode
    set beresp.ttl = 10s;
    set beresp.grace = 1h;
    #set beresp.keep = 24h;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    std.syslog(180, "RECV: deliver");

    #Cache
    set resp.http.grace = req.http.grace;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    std.syslog(180, "RECV: hit************************");

    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # normal hit
        return (deliver);
    }
    # We have no fresh fish. Lets look at the stale ones.
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        # Backend is healthy. Limit age to 10s.
        if (obj.ttl + 10s > 0s) {
            set req.http.grace = "normal(limited)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # No candidate for grace. Fetch a fresh object.
            return(miss);
        }
    } else {
        # backend is sick - use full grace
        if (obj.ttl + obj.grace > 0s) {
            set req.http.grace = "full";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # no graced object.
            return (miss);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when I get the log messages:
tail -f /var/log/messages

I just get the next steps:

```
varnishd[11801]: RECV: recv
varnishd[11801]: RECV: hash
varnishd[11801]: RECV: backend
varnishd[11801]: RECV: deliver
```

For this I know that the subroutine "vcl_hit" never is executed, so when the webserver is gone down, immediately I get an error messsage from varnish instead the cache from varnish:

```
Error 503 Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:
XID: 164960

Varnish cache server
```

Any idea to get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpage that we use have a session for the users, so we need identify when a user login or not.

With the previous configuration even if the cookie is empty, the default varnish configuration doesn't make cache for requests with cookies.

So I added some lines to make content cacheable (explained in code):

```
sub vcl_recv {
    # intial state
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # If our backend is down, unset all cookies and serve pages from cache.
    if (!std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
      unset req.http.cookie;
    }

    # NO cache si NO es get o head --> ejm, post, read, delete, etc
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # If server is healthy && user is in session --> no cache
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.cookie ~ "some_cookie=") {
            /* Not cacheable by default */
            return (pass);
        }
    }

    return(hash);
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    #Cache - grace mode
    set beresp.ttl = 10s;
    #set beresp.ttl = 1h;
    set beresp.grace = 1h;
    set beresp.keep = 24h;

    set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=3600";
}
```

The others subroutines have the same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the response from the backend is "uncacheable".

Does it have any `Cache-Control` header set by default? or cookies?

You can unset that header or set it to another value that allows caching:

`unset beresp.http.Cache-Control`

If you want that header to be `private, no-cache` when sent to the client to prevent upstream caching, then reset it in `vcl_deliver`

Comment: I tried creating a file returning just the time and setting the header:

        header('Cache-Control: public');
        echo "This page was last modified: ".date("d.m.Y H:i:s",time());

It worked just the first time, caching the content for 1 minute, but after that, I can't get the cache of that file.

Comment: I tried using:

"unset beresp.http.Cache-Control;" or
"set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "max-age=3600";"

in vcl_backend_response, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The only major difference between your config and mine is that all my times are in seconds. Could you try `beresp.grace = 3600s;` just to see if it works? Another trick is to set a response header as a debug logger so you can see under which condition the request was processed: `set req.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "hit";`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solved the problem based on your comments, and I published the solution.